# 'Driver' object has no attribute 'window_handles'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror, window-handles

I have a scenario where clicking on a link opens a new tab and next actions are to be performed on the new tab. I am using the following code snippet to achieve the same (Extra print statements are just to verify the results at each step):

```
    print("Switch to window tests - a")
    window_before = self.driver.window_handles[0]
    print("Current Window Handle - 1",self.driver.current_window_handle)
    print("Current Window Handle - 2",self.driver.window_handles[0])
    print(window_before)

    self.view_FormID = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="find-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a')))
    self.view_FormID.click()
    print("view_FormID link clicked")

    print("Switch to window tests - b")
    window_after = self.driver.window_handles[1]
    print("Current Window Handle - 1", self.driver.current_window_handle)
    print("Current Window Handle - 2", self.driver.window_handles[1])
    self.driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

Running the above code throws the error: "'Driver' object has no attribute 'window_handles'"

I don't find relevant solutions on any of the forums.
Could someone please take a look into what I may be missing?

Thanks so much!

PS: The code snippet above is a part of a page object in my POM;
FWIW, I am unable to reference any webdriver function here - so I guess the problem is in the way webdriver objects are supposed to be called in the page objects, which I am unable to figure out!
I have already spent ~2 days trying to figure out - so any help is much much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

winHandls=driver.window_handles

driver.switch_to.window(winHandls[index])

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and responding, Aayush! The improvement you suggest is explicitly initializing window handles first and then use it via indexes (and I was jumping to the second part directly, I guess). Unfortunately, I still get the same error :| Any more thoughts?

Comment: I added a PS in my original post - in case that helps